# Crear menu y dificultad en pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, pygame

Tengo todo listo solo me falta crear el menu y dificultad que no se donde ponerlos , el codigo completo es este

```
import pygame, sys, os, random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
#Se crea la ventana y le damos un titulo
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((397,660))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mastermind!')
#Se asignan los colores a utilizar y los guardamos con sus nombres 
respectivos
GREY = (127,127,127)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
font = pygame.font.SysFont('agencyfb', 24)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Carga las imagenes del juego en general data
def Cargar_Imagen(name, colorkey=None): 
  #Carga y guarda las imagenes de la carpeta Diseño
  fullname = os.path.join('data', name)
  try:
    image = pygame.image.load(fullname)
    #Muestra un error si la imagen no es encontrada y dice el nombre de la imagen faltante
  except pygame.error, message:
    print 'No se puede cargar imagen:', name
    raise SystemExit, message
  if colorkey is not None:
    if colorkey is -1:
        colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
    image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
  return image, image.get_rect()

class Boton_Colores(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,image):
      pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
      self.image, self.rect = Cargar_Imagen(image)
    def setCords(self,x,y):
      self.rect.topleft = x,y
      screen.blit(self.image, (x,y))
    def pressed(self,mouse):
       if mouse[0] > self.rect.topleft[0]:
          if mouse[1] > self.rect.topleft[1]:
              if mouse[0] < self.rect.bottomright[0]:
                 if mouse[1] < self.rect.bottomright[1]:
                    return True
                 else: return False
              else: return False
          else: return False
       else: return False


class TABLERO:
#Inicia el tablero y los demas elementos
def __init__(self):
    #Crea el tablero
    self.Tablero = ["g  g  g  g  g", 
                  "g  g  g  g  g",
                  "g  g  g  g  g",
                  "g  g  g  g  g",
                  "g  g  g  g  g",
                  "g  g  g  g  g",
                  "g  g  g  g  g",
                  "g  g  g  g  g",
                  "g  g  g  g  g",
                  "g  g  g  g  g",
                  "g  g  g  g  g",
                  "g  g  g  g  g",
                  "g  g  g  g  g",
                  "g  g  g  g  g",
                  "g  g  g  g  g",]
    #Tablero de las fichas blancas y negras
    self.Fichas_NB = ["g  g  g  g  g",  
                    "g  g  g  g  g",
                    "g  g  g  g  g",
                    "g  g  g  g  g",
                    "g  g  g  g  g",
                    "g  g  g  g  g",
                    "g  g  g  g  g",
                    "g  g  g  g  g",
                    "g  g  g  g  g",
                    "g  g  g  g  g",
                    "g  g  g  g  g",
                    "g  g  g  g  g",
                    "g  g  g  g  g",
                    "g  g  g  g  g",
                    "g  g  g  g  g",]
    #Botones donde se muestra la opcion elegida                
    self.Eleccion = ["g", "g", "g", "g","g"]
    #Mueve todo el set donde estan los colores hacia la derecha o izquierda (X)
    self.Set_x = 298
    #Mueve todo el set donde estan los colores hacia arriba o abajo (Y)
    self.Set_y = 360
    #Posicion donde estan los colores que se eligiran
    self.Set_e = 625
    #Asigna imagenes a los botones dependiendo de su color
    self.Boton_AZ = Boton_Colores('bluepeg.png')
    self.Boton_R = Boton_Colores('redpeg.png')
    self.Boton_A = Boton_Colores('yellowpeg.png')
    self.Boton_N = Boton_Colores('orangepeg.png')
    self.Boton_M = Boton_Colores('purppeg.png')
    self.Boton_V = Boton_Colores('greenpeg.png')
    #Formato en que estan los numeros
    #tamaño de los numeros
    self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('algerian', 14)
    self.font2 = pygame.font.SysFont('algerian', 4)

#Funcion donde se generan las filas de casillas y numeros al lado de ellas    
def Casilla_Num(self):
    #Genera los numeros antes de las filas de los intentos
    self.Num_Filas = 1
    #Mueve las casillas de intento en el eje X
    self.bx = 30
    #Mueve las casillas de intento en el eje Y
    self.by = 100
    #El contado de filas recorre el tablero
    for filas in self.Tablero:
        #Genera las filas 
        self.g = str(self.Num_Filas)
        self.text = self.font.render(self.g, 1, (10, 10, 10))
        #Muestra los numeros en la posicion X e Y indicadas
        screen.blit(self.text, (self.bx - 23, self.by)) #el 23 es la posicion en x
        #Se le suma 1 a los numeros generados para ir de forma creciente
        self.Num_Filas += 1
        pygame.display.update()
        #se asignan los colores a las filas de los intentos
        for col in filas:
            if col == "g":
                screen.blit(gris_peg, (self.bx, self.by))
            elif col == "r":
                screen.blit(rojo_peg, (self.bx, self.by))
            elif col == "az":
                screen.blit(azul_peg, (self.bx, self.by))
            elif col == "v":
                screen.blit(verde_peg, (self.bx, self.by))
            elif col == "m":
                screen.blit(morado_peg, (self.bx, self.by))
            elif col == "a":
                screen.blit(amarillo_peg, (self.bx, self.by))
            elif col == "n":
                screen.blit(naranjo_peg, (self.bx, self.by))
            else:
                continue
            self.bx += 35
        #Se le suma 35 al eje Y  de las casillas para que pase a la siguiente   
        self.by += 35
        #Se mantiene en la misma posicion en el eje X
        self.bx = 30
        pygame.display.flip()




def Fichas(self):#Le da posicion en el eje X e Y a las fichas
    self.Fichas_x = 205
    self.Fichas_y = 110
    for filas in self.Fichas_NB:
        for col in filas:
            if col == "g":
                screen.blit(Ficha_Gris, (self.Fichas_x, self.Fichas_y))
            elif col == "n":
                screen.blit(Ficha_Negra, (self.Fichas_x, self.Fichas_y))
            elif col == "b":
                screen.blit(Ficha_Blanca, (self.Fichas_x, self.Fichas_y))
            else:
                continue
            self.Fichas_x += 18
        self.Fichas_y += 35
        self.Fichas_x = 205
        pygame.display.flip()


def Color_Botones(self):
    #Le da color a la sombra de la tabla que contiene los colores a seleccionar
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (self.Set_x + 3, self.Set_y + 3, 90,110))
    #Le da color a la tabla que contiene los colores a seleccionar
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (self.Set_x,self.Set_y,90,110))
    #Le suma valores a los eje X e Y del set ,dandole nuevas posiciones a los colores
    self.Boton_R.setCords(self.Set_x+10,self.Set_y+5)
    self.Boton_N.setCords(self.Set_x+50,self.Set_y+5)
    self.Boton_A.setCords(self.Set_x+10, self.Set_y +40)
    self.Boton_V.setCords(self.Set_x+50, self.Set_y+40)
    self.Boton_AZ.setCords(self.Set_x+10, self.Set_y+75)
    self.Boton_M.setCords(self.Set_x+50, self.Set_y+75)
    pygame.display.update()
#Funcion que crea la filas que contendra los colores seleccionados
def Fila_Selec(self):
    #Mueve la fila en el eje X
    self.bx = 30
    #Pone el color seleccionado en la fila de elecciones
    for filas in self.Eleccion:
        #Si aun no elige un color la fila se quedara con el color gris hasta que seleccione uno
        if filas == "g":
            screen.blit(gris_peg, (self.bx, self.Set_e))
        elif filas == "r":
            screen.blit(rojo_peg, (self.bx, self.Set_e))
        elif filas == "az":
            screen.blit(azul_peg, (self.bx, self.Set_e))
        elif filas == "v":
            screen.blit(verde_peg, (self.bx, self.Set_e))
        elif filas == "m":
            screen.blit(morado_peg, (self.bx, self.Set_e))
        elif filas == "a":
            screen.blit(amarillo_peg, (self.bx, self.Set_e))
        elif filas == "n":
            screen.blit(naranjo_peg, (self.bx, self.Set_e))
        else:
            continue
        self.bx += 35
        pygame.display.flip()       

def Verificador(self, Eleccion):
    self.strikes1 = []
    self.strikes2 = []
    self.blackpeg=0
    self.whitepeg=0
    self.bwcount = []
    for i in range(len(Eleccion)):
        if Eleccion[i] == solucion[i]:
            self.blackpeg += 1
            self.strikes1.append(i)
            self.strikes2.append(i)
            self.bwcount.append("n")
    for x in range(len(solucion)):
        for y in range(len(solucion)):
            if x not in self.strikes1 and y not in self.strikes2:
                if Eleccion[x] == solucion[y]:
                    self.whitepeg += 1
                    self.strikes1.append(x)
                    self.strikes2.append(i)
                    self.bwcount.append("b")
        self.Fichas_NB[Turno] = self.bwcount

def Gana(self):
    screen.blit(winbg, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(5000)
    exit()

def Pierde(self):
    screen.blit(losebg, (0,0))
    self.bx = 115
    #Genera la solucion y la imprime una vez el usuario pierde
    for filas in solucion:
        if filas == "g":
            screen.blit(gris_peg, (self.bx, 400))
        elif filas == "r":
            screen.blit(rojo_peg, (self.bx, 400))
        elif filas == "az":
            screen.blit(azul_peg, (self.bx, 400))
        elif filas == "v":
            screen.blit(verde_peg, (self.bx, 400))
        elif filas == "m":
            screen.blit(morado_peg, (self.bx, 400))
        elif filas == "a":
            screen.blit(amarillo_peg, (self.bx, 400))
        elif filas == "n":
            screen.blit(naranjo_peg, (self.bx, 400))
        else:
            continue
        self.bx += 35
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(5000)
    exit()

def Dar_Respuesta():
#generates the solution which the player must guess
availcolors = ("r", "n", "a", "v", "az", "m")
answer = [random.choice(availcolors) for i in range(5)]
return answer

def Fondo_Texto():
#Carga y guarda la imagen de fondo
Fondo, Fondo_rect = Cargar_Imagen('FONDO.jpg')
screen.blit(Fondo,(0,0))
#Le da color,grosor y posicion a la linea superior
pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, (30, 55), (350, 55), 5)
#Le da color,grosor y posicion a la linea inferior
pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, (30, 620), (620, 620), 5)
#Genera al texto en la parte superior 
heading_text = font.render("Sus Elecciones",1,(0,0,0))
#Da la posicion donde se se encontrara el texto
heading_textpos = (65, 65)
#Muestra en pantalla el texto en la posicion y su color
screen.blit(heading_text, heading_textpos)
pygame.display.update()

gris_peg, gris_rect = Cargar_Imagen('mmempty.png')
rojo_peg, rojo_peg_rect = Cargar_Imagen('redpeg.png')
azul_peg, azul_peg_rect = Cargar_Imagen('bluepeg.png')
verde_peg, verde_peg_rect = Cargar_Imagen('greenpeg.png')
morado_peg, morado_peg_rect = Cargar_Imagen('purppeg.png')
amarillo_peg, amarillo_peg_rect = Cargar_Imagen('yellowpeg.png')
naranjo_peg, naranjo_peg_rect = Cargar_Imagen('orangepeg.png')
Ficha_Gris, Ficha_Gris_rect = Cargar_Imagen('bwempty1.png')
Ficha_Blanca, Ficha_Blanca_rect = Cargar_Imagen('bwwhite.png')
Ficha_Negra, Ficha_Negra_rect = Cargar_Imagen('bwblack.png')
winbg, winbg_rect = Cargar_Imagen('mmbgwin.jpg')
losebg, losebg_rect = Cargar_Imagen('mmbglose.jpg')


#Menu General

Fondo_Texto()

Tablero = TABLERO()

solucion = Dar_Respuesta()
print solucion
Turno = 0
Tablero.Casilla_Num()
Tablero.Color_Botones()
Tablero.Fichas()
Tablero.Fila_Selec()
deltat = clock.tick(10)
#Contador de los colores elegidos
Color_Num = 0
guessresult = []
pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
#Se le asignan los intentos y los turnos que ha realizado
while Turno <= 15:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        exit()
    #SI los turnos son iguales a los intentos permitidos, el jugador pierde    
    elif Turno == 15:
        #Le muestra una imagen diciendo que perdio
        Tablero.Pierde()
    elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and Color_Num < 5:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if Tablero.Boton_AZ.pressed(pos) == True:#bluebut
            Tablero.Eleccion[Color_Num] = "az"
            Tablero.Fila_Selec()
            Color_Num += 1
        elif Tablero.Boton_A.pressed(pos) == True:
            Tablero.Eleccion[Color_Num] = "a"
            Tablero.Fila_Selec()
            Color_Num += 1

        elif Tablero.Boton_N.pressed(pos) == True:
            Tablero.Eleccion[Color_Num] = "n"
            Tablero.Fila_Selec()
            Color_Num += 1

        elif Tablero.Boton_M.pressed(pos) == True:
            Tablero.Eleccion[Color_Num] = "m"
            Tablero.Fila_Selec()
            Color_Num += 1

        elif Tablero.Boton_V.pressed(pos) == True:
            Tablero.Eleccion[Color_Num] = "v"
            Tablero.Fila_Selec()
            Color_Num += 1

        elif Tablero.Boton_R.pressed(pos) == True:
            Tablero.Eleccion[Color_Num] = "r"
            Tablero.Fila_Selec()
            Color_Num += 1
        else:
            continue
    elif Color_Num == 5:
        Tablero.Tablero[Turno] = Tablero.Eleccion
        Tablero.Casilla_Num()
        Tablero.Verificador(Tablero.Eleccion)
        Tablero.Fichas()
        Tablero.Eleccion = ["g", "g", "g", "g","g"]
        Turno += 1
        Tablero.Fila_Selec()
        Tablero.Fichas()
        Color_Num = 0
        if Tablero.blackpeg == 5:
            Tablero.Gana()
            break   
    else:
        continue
```

Mi idea es algo asi

```
if event.key==KEYDOWN:
   if event.key==K_SPACE:

elif event.key==KEYDOWN:
    if event.key==K_ENTER:
```

Pero no se mucho de en que parte del codigo deberia ponerlo para que no me de error y podrian darme una idea para hacer todo el proceso del juego pero esta vez con 4 casillas en vez de 5? asi ejemplo, si presiona espacio se inicia el juego en modo dificil (5 casillas) o si presiona enter se inicia el juego en modo facil (4 casillas), tambien se agradece toda la ayuda y si quieren darme sugerencias de poner mas comentarios las agradeceria

Comment: Por ahora te comento para el menu, ya luego vemos que acciones poner dentro de el para hacer la seleccion de dificultad o hasta unos botones se pueden hacer, cuando este mas desocupado revisamos lo de la dificultad, podrias especificar que variable representa a las casillas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedan pocos dias y quiero terminarlo pronto pero en clases no enseñan nada de esto y he debido leer mucho. La verdad no se me ocurrio una forma mas facil de generar las casillas que ponerlas dentro de la clase tablero e ir poniendolas manualmente, por eso hay tantas filas y columnas que tiene 'g', se supone que el g es por la casilla que esta vacio mientras el usuario no presione un color... no se si se entiende mucho :(

Comment: Puedes generar una matriz de X por Y casillas, revisa en el primer tutorial la parte de matrices, te añadire a la respuesta una forma de generarla

Comment: Gracias , he visto pero aun asi no entiendo y el tiempo se me agota :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Para hacer un menu:

Debes buscar la manera de generar otra pantalla encima de la de tu juego actual. Para ello puedes definir una función o clase que te genere otro game_loop o ciclo de juego, es decir, algo como el `while Turno <= 15:`.

Yo lo hago de esta manera:

```
import pygame

def generar_otra_pantalla():
    otra_pantalla = True
    while otra_pantalla:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                #IMPORTANTE ESTA ACCION, DE MODO QUE SI PULSAN DE NUEVO LA TECLA SE OCULTE EL MENU
                    otra_pantalla = False
                # COLOCAMOS EL COLOR DEL MENU
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        # DIBUJAMOS COSAS
        dibujar("cuadrado")
        dibujar("menu de acciones")
        # ACTUALIZAMOS EL DISPLAY CON UPDATE SE USA AQUI PARA 
        # UNICAMENTE ACTUALIZAR LA PORCION DE PANTALLA QUE ESTAMOS USANDO, NO TODO.
        # PORQUE DE LO CONTRARIO BORRARIA LO QUE ESTABA DEBAJO, 
        # DIGAMOS ERA UN MENU DE PAUSA, SI USAMOS FLIP CUANDO QUITEMOS EL MENU NO QUEDARA NADA
        pygame.display.update()

        # Y LUEGO PONEMOS EL RELOJ RAPIDO PARA QUE SEA UN RENDERIZADO PERMANENTE
        reloj_juego.tick(5)
```

Y esa función la llamo desde el main_loop o loop principal:

```
pygame.init()

# SE IGNORA LA DEFINICION DE RELOJ Y DEMAS ELEMENTOS BASICOS
GAME_END = False

import otra_pantalla

#: Bucle Principal
while not GAME_END:
#: Manejador de eventos
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                otra_pantalla()

    # OJO EL UPDATE VA A CARGAR LOS DIBUJOS QUE HAGAMOS EN EL LIENZO 
    # LLAMEMOSLO ASI DE otra_pantalla 
    # AQUI EL FLIP VA A ACTUALIZAR LA PANTALLA CON LO QUE SE HA TRAZADO 
    # EN GENERAL, POR TANTO, CUANDO PULSAMOS LA TECLA ASIGNADA (q) SE
    # CARGA OTRA PANTALLA Y SOLO SE ACTUALIZA ELLA, LUEGO
    # AL PULSARLA OTRA VEZ QUEDA EL MENU ANTERIOR

    pygame.display.flip()
    reloj_juego.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

### Para la dificultad

**Puedes seguir estos tutoriales:**

**1.** Programar Juegos Arcade con Pygame (esta completo, tiene hasta
    manejo de sprites)

http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?lang=en

Esta en español pero hay hipervinculos que no funcionan, en el sitio en ingles funciona todo perfecto.

**2.** Thenewboston pygame tutorial:

Este tiene dos cursos, el primero haces un juego de disparos, luego uno de carreras, explica menus, colisiones, pausa, y demas, muy bueno.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5F-aGDIYaM&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAjkwJocj7vlc_mFU-4wXJq

Comment: como lo agregago una imagen al menu? alli le tengo escrita que si apreta espacio incia el juego en modo facil y si apreta enter sera en modo dificil pero se si es igual a como lo hice o es diferente... tambien de como lo hago para que inicie en el nivel elegido?

Comment: en ese codigo que te puse debes hacer como si fuera tu juego base, es decir, mostrar alli todos los elementos y luego al darle enter o espacio que ejecute tu juego principal, que es el que se llama "Menu General", encierralo todo en una funcion